# Error al correr un procedure en Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola estoy trantando de correr este procedure en mi BD pero me esta tirando un error que es el siguiente : **PLS-00363: expression 'TO_CHAR' cannot be used as an assignment target**
Todo lo declarado son OUT nose si  servira este ultimo dato aportado. Y una ultima consulta, se me fueron otorgados los permimos para ver paquetes, store procedure y tablas, pero en este caso  no lo puedo ver. Que podria hacer? Mil graciias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  DECLARE 
            desceani VARCHAR(60);
            cunimedi VARCHAR (3);
            precio_uni NUMBER;
            precio_uni_siva NUMBER;
            codretor NUMBER;
            txtretor VARCHAR(200);
        BEGIN  
        desceani := '';
        cunimedi := '';
        precio_uni := '';
        precio_uni_siva := '';
        codretor := '';
        txtretor := '';
            va3.validar_plu(1, 499298, 561, '30517307099', 'SUCURSAL', '20210629', 'Alta', 'PVP',desceani, cunimedi, precio_uni, precio_uni_siva,codretor,txtretor);
            COMMIT;
        END;
```

Comment: Le estás asignando VARCHAR `''` a los NUMBER (`precio_uni`, `cor_retor`, `precio_uni_siva`). Supondría que los quieres inicializar con cero o algo así.

Comment: Todas las variables en PL/SQL por omisión tienen valor NULO, de manera que no se requiere la asignación de un string nulo y no aplica la asignación de un string nulo a las variables numéricas precio_uni , precio_uni_siva y codretor.